# 2sxc | Dnn Object for 'Tag' field in Dnn page settings

Tags: dotnetnuke, taxonomy, 2sxc

I am using one of the 2sxc Sherlock snippet Dnn objects to filter further what displays to screen as follows:

```
@if(@Dnn.Tab.KeyWords == "Living")
{
```

which works fine....but I would prefer if the Dnn.Tab 'Tag' field could be used as a Dnn object just like the Dnn.Tab.KeyWords can be used?

(As Tags has a dropdown vocabulary hierarchy as opposed to just a textbox field for the keywords)

[image]

These Dnn object snippets are based off the TabInfo Class (http://dotnetnukeru.com/dnndocs/api/html/T_DotNetNuke_Entities_Tabs_TabInfo.htm) which don't have anything for the 'Tag' field in Dnn page settings.

I am trying to have a filter that if Dnn Tab(page) has 'x' Tag assigned then display '...'

I can work away with the Dnn 'keywords' field as a filter but just prefer to allow user to select filter from 'tag' dropdown to minimize human error! Also, even if it was possible to convert the current Dnn 'Keywords' field to a pre populated dropdown field would be equally sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the tag entries are not simple tab properties.  To do this, you are going to have to dig into DNN's taxonomy component.  You might get some help starting here:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/taxonomy